# rowSums - 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: r

This is really hard to explain but basically I have a dataset where people completed a wordsearch task. By using the following code I indexed the letters of the wordsearch by finding their numbers in the descriptions. I put them into a matrix so that I can use them to index from the dataset later:

```
number <- "#101"
wordsearch <- matrix(rep(0, times = 16 * ncol(data)), nrow = 16, ncol = ncol(data))

for (i in 1:9){
  for (j in 1:ncol(data)){
    wordsearch[i,j] <- grepl(number, data[1, j], fixed = T)
  }
  number <- paste("#10", (i+1), sep = "")
}
number <- "#110"
for (i in 10:15) {
  for (j in 34:217){
    wordsearch[i,j] <- grepl(number, data[1, j], fixed = T)
  }
  number <- paste("#1", (i+1), sep = "")
}
number <- "#3"
for (j in 1:ncol(data)){
  wordsearch[16,j] <- grepl(number, data[1, j], fixed = T)
}
```

This part works perfectly. Then I want to sum the number of letters people found for each word and create new columns for each word and add to the dataset. First I got the error that 'x must be numeric' so I did data[is.na(data] <- 0
And then I did the following code:

```
col <- seq(261, by = 1, length.out = 16)

for (i in 1:16){
  d2[, col[i]] <- rowSums(d2[, wordsearch[i, ] == 1])
}
```

I literally just did that with another dataset and it worked fine but now I'm getting the "x' must be an array of at least two dimensions". Can someone help?

Comment: Check the dimension of `d2[, wordsearch[i, ] == 1]` and compare it to the dimension of your "literally just another datatset".

Comment: If `d2[, wordsearch[i, ] == 1]` has only one column, R will convert it to a vector (1 dimension). You can prevent that with `d2[, wordsearch[i, ] == 1, drop=FALSE] `.